# configure a rabbit mq host using configuration api

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using MassTransit 3.5 and RabbitMq

I want to make rabbitMq Host but it is giving me an error

this is my code

```
var hostName = new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost");
IBusControl busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(c =>
{
    IRabbitMqHost temp = c.Host(hostName, h =>
    {
        h.Username("admin");
        h.Password("admin");
    });
 });
```

this line gives me the error

```
IRabbitMqHost temp = c.Host(hostName, h =>
```

> "Reference to type 'IPipeConfigurator<>' claims it is defined in
>   'MassTransit but it could not be found"

Comment: Your code seems fine, update your packages, restore them, clean dlls, restart vs and build again

Comment: Thnx man i update the package and fix error

Comment: you are welcome